# React Router with Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I am pretty new to react and I am now trying to use React Router and Material UI together.

I have my Layout file which uses Navigation drawer from material UI and I have placed my menu on the left and the content on the right as shown in the pic below

What I want to do is, when I click on the `Test Comp` it should load the `TestComp.js` component on the right and so on for `Test Comp One` to load `TestCompOne.js`.

I have been through the ReactRouter code with Links, Switch and Route but I am not exactly sure where to place them.

I tried adding the following code for my Layout file which should have the Router but I am sure I have not done it right
Error I get is

```
Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>
```

could you please correct me to get this right please

[image]

index.js

```
import Layout from './Layout/Layout'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Layout/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

component - TestComp.js

```
import React from "react"

export default class TestComp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>test component for test</h1>
        );
    }
}
```

Component TestCompOne.js

```
import React from "react"

export default class TestCompOne extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>test component ONE for test</h1>
        );
    }
}
```

I am pasting the entire Layout file which is a bit big but the main area is the `drawer` which is the left menu and content to be displayed is where I added the `<Router>`.
Apologies if this is completely wrong way of doing, please suggest

Component Layout.js - which has the Navigation drawer from material UI and where I want to add Router to open individual components

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import Hidden from '@material-ui/core/Hidden';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { MenuItem, MenuList } from '@material-ui/core';
import TestComp from '../Components/TestComp'
import TestCompOne from '../Components/TestCompOne'
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link
  } from "react-router-dom";

const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  drawer: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: drawerWidth,
      flexShrink: 0,
    },
  },
  appBar: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
      marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    },
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      display: 'none',
    },
  },
  // necessary for content to be below app bar
  toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
  },
}));

function ResponsiveDrawer(props) {
  const { container } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [sampleText, setSampleText] = React.useState("test");

  const handleDrawerToggle = () => {
    setMobileOpen(!mobileOpen);
  };

  const testCompClicked = () => {
    setSampleText("Test Comp")
  };

  const testCompOneClicked = () => {
    setSampleText("Test Comp One")
  };

  const drawer = (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />
      <Divider />
      <MenuList>
        <MenuItem onClick={testCompClicked} component={Link} to="/testcomp">
          <ListItemIcon>
            <InboxIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Test Comp" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={testCompOneClicked} component={Link} to="/testcompone">
          <ListItemIcon>
            <MailIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Test Comp One" />
        </MenuItem>
      </MenuList>
      <Divider />
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar} style={{ background: '#78a02e'}}>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            edge="start"
            onClick={handleDrawerToggle}
            className={classes.menuButton}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
            Responsive drawer
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <nav className={classes.drawer} aria-label="mailbox folders">
        {/* The implementation can be swapped with js to avoid SEO duplication of links. */}
        <Hidden smUp implementation="css">
          <Drawer
            container={container}
            variant="temporary"
            anchor={theme.direction === 'rtl' ? 'right' : 'left'}
            open={mobileOpen}
            onClose={handleDrawerToggle}
            classes={{
              paper: classes.drawerPaper,
            }}
            ModalProps={{
              keepMounted: true, // Better open performance on mobile.
            }}
          >
            {drawer}
          </Drawer>
        </Hidden>
        <Hidden xsDown implementation="css">
          <Drawer
            classes={{
              paper: classes.drawerPaper,
            }}
            variant="permanent"
            open
          >
            {drawer}
          </Drawer>
        </Hidden>
      </nav>
      <main className={classes.content}>
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        <h1>{sampleText}</h1>
        <h3>I want to show individual components using React Rounter when I press them from the left menu</h3>
        <Router>
            <Switch>
            <Route path="/testcomp">
                <TestComp />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/testcompone">
                <TestCompOne />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/">
                <TestComp />
            </Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

ResponsiveDrawer.propTypes = {
  /**
   * Injected by the documentation to work in an iframe.
   * You won't need it on your project.
   */
  container: PropTypes.any,
};

export default ResponsiveDrawer;
```

Comment: You need to put the Links inside the `Router` as well

Comment: As the above comment said, you may want to place the `<Router />` outside as a top-level parent

Comment: then how about the clicks for menu items?

Answer (score 1):

The `Links` need to be within the `<Router>` environment.
Try

```
  return (
    <Router>
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar} style={{ background: '#78a02e'}}>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            edge="start"
            onClick={handleDrawerToggle}
            className={classes.menuButton}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
            Responsive drawer
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <nav className={classes.drawer} aria-label="mailbox folders">
        {/* The implementation can be swapped with js to avoid SEO duplication of links. */}
        <Hidden smUp implementation="css">
          <Drawer
            container={container}
            variant="temporary"
            anchor={theme.direction === 'rtl' ? 'right' : 'left'}
            open={mobileOpen}
            onClose={handleDrawerToggle}
            classes={{
              paper: classes.drawerPaper,
            }}
            ModalProps={{
              keepMounted: true, // Better open performance on mobile.
            }}
          >
            {drawer}
          </Drawer>
        </Hidden>
        <Hidden xsDown implementation="css">
          <Drawer
            classes={{
              paper: classes.drawerPaper,
            }}
            variant="permanent"
            open
          >
            {drawer}
          </Drawer>
        </Hidden>
      </nav>
      <main className={classes.content}>
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        <h1>{sampleText}</h1>
        <h3>I want to show individual components using React Rounter when I press them from the left menu</h3>
            <Switch>
            <Route path="/testcomp">
                <TestComp />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/testcompone">
                <TestCompOne />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/">
                <TestComp />
            </Route>
            </Switch>
          </main>
        </div>
    </Router>
  );
```